# $(PDP^{-1}-I)(PDP^{-1}-2I)=P(D-I)(D-2I)P^{-1}$ I can't follow the factorization for these matrixs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I don't know how we were able to factor these matrices like this

$(PDP^{-1}-I)(PDP^{-1}-2I)=P(D-I)(D-2I)P^{-1}$

how do you factor the LHS to get the RHS

Comment: $PDP^{-1}-I=P(D-I)P^{-1}$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $PDP^{-1}-I = P(D-I)P^{-1} $ and $PDP^{-1} - 2I = P(D-2I)P^{-1}$. Thus \begin{align} (PDP^{-1}-I)(PDP^{-1}-2I) &= P(D-I)P^{-1} P(D-2I)P^{-1} \\ &= P(D-I)(D-2I)P^{-1}\end{align}

Comment: cheers, it became clear moments after i asked the question what my brain was blocked on, $PIP^{-1}=I$ my brain took a while to see it